# Why aren't the tabs switching?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to take the below block from a template:
https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard-angular2

[image]

After launching the project on the local computer, the link **http://localhost:4200/homepage** opens (if the user is authorized). When I hover over the website tab, the link **http://localhost:4200/#messages** is displayed. If I click on it, it is redirected to the link **http://localhost:4200/homepage**. And we return to the starting position. Anchor doesn't work, tabs don't switch.
Help find the error.
My project structure:

[image]

Code from home-page.component.html:

```html
    <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header card-header-tabs card-header-primary">
            <div class="nav-tabs-navigation">
              <div class="nav-tabs-wrapper">
                <span class="nav-tabs-title">Tasks:</span>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a mat-button class="nav-link active" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">
                      <i class="material-icons">bug_report</i> Bugs
                      <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a mat-button class="nav-link" href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">
                      <i class="material-icons">code</i> Website
                      <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a mat-button class="nav-link" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">
                      <i class="material-icons">cloud</i> Server
                      <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept
                      through metro Detroit
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Create 4 Invisible User Experiences you Never Knew About</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept
                      through metro Detroit
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Lines From Great Russian Literature? Or E-mails From My Boss?</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Flooded: One year later, assessing what was lost and what was found when a ravaging rain swept
                      through metro Detroit
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                          <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                              <span class="check"></span>
                                                          </span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>Sign contract for "What are conference organizers afraid of?"</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```
Code from app-routing.module.ts:

    const routes: Routes = [
      {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
      {
        path: '', component: HomeRouteComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: '/homepage', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent},
        ]
      },
      {path: '**', component: LoginPageComponent}
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    }

Code from auth.guard.ts:

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
      constructor(private localAuthService: AuthService,
                  private localRouter: Router) {
      }
    
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        if (this.localAuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.localRouter.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
      }
    }
```

Code from auth.service.ts:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthService {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      loginUser(userLogin: string, userPassword: string): boolean {
        return userLogin === '1' && userPassword === '2';
      }
    
      isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return localStorage.getItem('isLogin') && localStorage.getItem('isLogin') === '1';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting 404 error?

Comment: @DRASHTI DOBARIYA  - No. After launching the project on the local computer, the link http://localhost:4200/homepage opens (if the user is authorized). When I hover over the website tab, the link http://localhost:4200/#messages is displayed. If I click on it, it is redirected to the link http://localhost:4200/homepage. And we return to the starting position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Analysis

> Why aren't the tabs switching?

Before we answer this question, lets ask 3 other questions

1. How are the Tabs switching?
2. What does `/#messages` mean?
3. What does below in the routes mean?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {
    path: '', component: HomeRouteComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/homepage', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent},
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: LoginPageComponent}
];
```

@Timothy has highlighted questions 2 and 3 so I will not explain much here. Simply to bind to a router you will need to use either

```html
<a routerLink='/messages' > Messages</a>
<a href='/#/messages' > Messages</a> <!--Note the /#/-->
<a [routerLink]='["messages"]'> Messages </a>
```

My advice, use the 3rd Option

To Qn3 , your routes match below

```
'/login' => LoginPageComponent (Unfortunately even logged in users will be able to visit this route. Consider implementing a Guest Guard)
'/' => Logged in User redirected to homepage
'/homepage' =>  Logged in User receives HomePageComponent
'**' => Redirect to login page (Consider implementing a NOTFOUND page instead)
```

Back to question 1.

> I need to solve a problem for my specific situation. Tabs should work.

So how are the tabs switching? Lets look at a skeleton of the html

```html
...
<a mat-button class="nav-link" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab"> ... </a>
...
<a mat-button class="nav-link" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab"> ... </a>
...
<a mat-button class="nav-link active" href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"> ...</a>
...
<div class="tab-pane active" id="profile"> ... </div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages"> ... </div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="settings"> ... </div>
```

**The Tabs are changing when the active class switches**

So we ask ourselves the next question, does visiting '/#messages' OR '/#/messages' of '/messages' change the class? NO. Therefore your problem is not with routing...

### Solution

A simple solution would be to use binding

In our TS we can have

```
activeTab = 'messages'
```

And in the html

```html
...
<a mat-button class="nav-link" [class.active]='activeTab === "settings"' (click)='activeTab = "settings"' href="#settings" data-toggle="tab"> ... </a>
...

...
<div class="tab-pane" [class.active]='activeTab === "settings"' id="settings"> ... </div>
```

Now the tabs will be switching as expected [**See Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xftqbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is with your links, In your template you are using `href="#messages"` to navigate, Which practically tells browser to navigate to current page with a given hash (this link is not processed by Angular, as @OwenKelvin added you can use `href="/#/messages` though). But actually in Angular you use [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) to navigate.

```
<a mat-button class="nav-link" routerLink="/messages" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="material-icons">code</i> Website
  <div class="ripple-container"></div>
</a>
```

Secondly if you need to debug routes you can use

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: false,
  enableTracing: true // enable route tracing in console
})
```

Third, I I think your routes must be something like

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
      {path: 'homepage', component: HomeRouteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
    ];
```

I also don't think that you need to navigate in route guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  if (this.localAuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
   return true;
  } else {
    this.localRouter.navigate(['/login']); // this line excessive
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but the statement `must use routerLink` is not true. You can simply change `href="#messages"` to `href="/#/messages" and everything will work

Comment: Fair addition @OwenKelvin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to configure the extra options in the Router.

Check out https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling

From that I think your app-routing.module.ts should look something like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {
    path: '', component: HomeRouteComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/homepage', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent},
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: LoginPageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false, anchorScrolling: 'enabled'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: ```{useHash: false, anchorScrolling: 'enabled'}``` Thanks for the advice. I made edits. Unfortunately it didn't help. No changes.